# Snapping multiple polylines to points nearby

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping

I have a network of polylines and nodes. Each polyline starts at a point and ends at other. To be more specific, the network consists of links and nodes.

The problem is that, the polylines are slightly (maybe feets) offset to the points. Is there any way that I can snap all the ends of the polylines to the nearest point??

Now the new network would have points exactly at ends of polylines.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @klewis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236798/snapping-multiple-polylines-to-points-nearby/259421#comment368950_236798):

> The[re] is a Snap tool in the Editing Tools toolBox. You should be
>   able to snap line ends to nearest Points.

[and](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236798/snapping-multiple-polylines-to-points-nearby/259421#comment368954_236798):

> Editing Tools is in the ArcToolbox, typically next to the map window.
>   Or ctrl-F, to open Search window, enter "Snap".

The [Snap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm) tool:

> Moves points or vertices to coincide exactly with the vertices, edges,
>   or end points of other features. Snapping rules can be specified to
>   control whether the input vertices are snapped to the nearest vertex,
>   edge, or endpoint within a specified distance.